# Jquery to create a popup div on hover?

Tags: jquery

[This](http://www.sohtanaka.com/web-design/fancy-thumbnail-hover-effect-w-jquery/) is a pretty cool jquery popup technique for an image. Does anyone know the best way to get a similar thing working to get a div-enclosed table as the pop-up? What I'm trying to do is let the user hover over an image to get a bigger version of the image plus a caption and other details.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think that's pretty simple just use Jquery.mouseover(fn)

```
$("#yourimage").mouseover(function() {
    $("#hidden_div").show();
}).mouseout(function() { 
    $("#hidden_div").hide();
});
```

Answer (score 5):

hover in jquery exists too: Jquery.hover(fn,fn)

See http://api.jquery.com/hover/